# I want convert this buffer to blob in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

```
file:
buffer: {type: 'Buffer', data: Array(599862)}
encoding: "7bit"
fieldname: "file"
mimetype: "application/msword"
originalname: "2020.doc"
size: 599862
[[Prototype]]: Object
file_location_new: "E:\\vimal\\aws_temp/candidate/resume-parser/09a45bd8-1b74-4fbc-8763-bad41d81cd6d.doc"
name: "09a45bd8-1b74-4fbc-8763-bad41d81cd6d.doc"
originalFilename: "2020.doc"
path: "/candidate/resume-parser"
schemaname: "cons"
size: 599862
type: "application/msword"
```

Comment: Is it a multer file object?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wOJ17W) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.   Console messages don't really help much.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.